# Add event listener to the items in an array

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an array with movieclips (r1, r2 etc) which are placed on stage dynamically every time there is a hittestobject. I want to add event listener to those movieclips in the array so that every time there is a click on them the ***last item*** to be removed. I have this code but it seems to be wrong because only the first element of the array is remove. Can you please help me?

```
var counter:int = 0;

function releaseToDrop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    Star(e.target).stopDrag();
    if (Star(e.target).hitTestObject(target))
    {
        removeChild(Star(e.target));
        var replace:Array = [r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8]
        addChild(replace[counter]);
        counter = counter+1; 
    }
    else
    {
        trace("No collision.");
        removeChild(Star(e.target));
    }
}

    replace[counter].addEventListener("click", bindClick(o));
    function bindClick(o)
    {
        replace.splice(replace.indexOf(replace[counter]),1); 
        trace(counter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future references adding addEventListener to the elements of an array so that every time there is a click on them the last item to be removed can be done by this code:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

var replace:Array = [r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8]

var counter:int = 0;

// Every time there is a hittestobject an element of the array is placed on stage
function releaseToDrop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    Star(e.target).stopDrag();
    if (Star(e.target).hitTestObject(target))
  {
    removeChild(Star(e.target));
          addChild(replace[counter]);
          counter = counter+1; 
    trace(counter);
  }
}

// The first element of the array has an eventListener and when is clicked the last item of that array shown on stage is removed

  var yourSprite:Sprite=new Sprite();
  replace.push(yourSprite);
  replace[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClickHandler, false, 0, true);
  function myClickHandler (e:MouseEvent):void
          {
    counter =counter-1;
    if (contains(replace[counter])) 
    removeChild(replace[counter]);
    trace(counter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For one, your *bindClick* function is inside the *releaseToDrop* function. This way that function will not be called. Also, try to use the static refence for the click event, so MouseEvent.Click instead of "click".
For your convenience, trace the current state of "counter" in the *bindClick* function, so you know what element will be removed. You will probably then find out where the flaw is in your logic.

A wise thing to to is also to check counter is not outside the scope of your array. So in *bindClick*, check for *counter < replace.length*. (for that the replace array of course has to be defined outside of the function scope of *releaseToDrop*.

Hope this gets you working in the right direction.

Comment: _A wise thing to to is also to check counter is not outside the scope of your array. So in bindClick, check for counter < replace.length. (for that the replace array of course has to be defined outside of the function scope of releaseToDrop_  I am not sure how i will do those. I edit my code above. Did i do it the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an event listener to every movie clip that you spawn, then in each event handler, add a conditional to check if the clicked movie clip is the **last** item, then remove it (or do whatever you need to to it).

You should also accept Chicken's advice.